# Why is this syntax error in select statement SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

When I use a select statement inside store procedured like

```
SELECT * FROM tableName
```

it executes but it is marked as syntax a error,

But if I write

```
SELECT * FROM 'tableName'
```

it´s not mark as a syntax error, but when executed, it says:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure proc, Line 264
>   Incorrect syntax near 'tableName'

How to correct it

Comment: Is `table` the actual name of your table or is it merely for illustration purposes? If the later, what exactly is the table name in question?

Comment: well, I put that only for example but could be any name

Comment: In fact my table is called, 'mat'

Comment: Please show the entire stored procedure.

Comment: Does the table exist? What's the message exactly? What follows `SELECT * FROM tableName`? Could it be `WITH...`?

Comment: So silly, The error is because the table at that time does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the OP stated in a comment, the syntax error occurs because the table does not exist at design time. The table is created by the stored procedure. I'd consider this to be an acceptable syntax error so long as it is documented inline where it occurs.